# google cloud endpoints discrepancy between documentation, and what works in my app

Tags: javascript, python, api, google-cloud-endpoints

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_js#enabling-a-javascript-client) states you should load your api from javascript like this:

```
var ROOT = 'https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api';
gapi.client.load('your_app_id', 'v1', function() {
    doSomethingAfterLoading();
}, ROOT);
```

But, what it seems to actually be is

```
var ROOT = 'https://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api';
gapi.client.load('your_api_name', 'v1', function() {
    doSomethingAfterLoading();
}, ROOT);
```

For example, I can pass "users" as the api name, and now the `users` object is defined as an attribute of `gapi.client`.

Just to be clear, my api is defined like this:

```
@endpoints.api(name='users',version='v1',
               description='The user service.')
class UserService(remote.Service):
    ...
```

So now, I wonder, am I doing something in an unintended way? And, since `/_ah/api/explorer` can find all the APIs that are defined, is there a way to have this function add all the apis I define without having to specify all their names in separate `gapi.client.load` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out, this is a bug in the documentation! We'll try to get if fixed ASAP.

You should check out the fully-baked [Tic Tac Toe sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python/).

In it, we show how to [load multiple APIs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python/blob/e6abf813c8232fef1f9b0f316b550236c93ee89f/static/js/base.js#L361) (among other things).

```
google.devrel.samples.ttt.init = function(apiRoot) {
  // Loads the OAuth and Tic Tac Toe APIs asynchronously, and triggers login
  // when they have completed.
  var apisToLoad;
  var callback = function() {
    if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
      google.devrel.samples.ttt.signin(true,
          google.devrel.samples.ttt.userAuthed);
    }
  }

  apisToLoad = 2; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
  gapi.client.load('tictactoe', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
  gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', callback);

  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.addEventListener('click', google.devrel.samples.ttt.clickSquare);
  }

  var reset = document.querySelector('#restartButton');
  reset.addEventListener('click', google.devrel.samples.ttt.resetGame);
};
```