# App Engine Cloud Endpoint Javascript library does not work

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I tried to enable Cloud Endpoint via [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_js).

After defining the API and doing some configuration, finally the API can be viewed and executed via [API Explorer](http://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer) successfully.

However, I cannot enable the Javascript client to run:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var ROOT = "https://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api";
      gapi.client.load('my-app-id', 'v1', function() {
        gapi.client.bigquery.query({
          'start_date': '2013-05-01',
          'end_date': '2013-05-02',
          'metrics': ['impr']
        }).execute(function(resp) {
          console.log(resp);
        });
      }, ROOT);
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>
</html>
```

I noticed the request failed during the Javascript execution, but I cannot figure out why.

**Request**

`https://my-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/my-app-id/v1/rpc?`

**Response**

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"notFound","message":"Not Found"}],"code":404,"message":"Not Found"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your API name, not `my-app-id`. Also, make sure your API is deployed and serving. If not, this would similarly cause a `404`.

See [google cloud endpoints discrepancy between documentation, and what works in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686387/google-cloud-endpoints-discrepancy-between-documentation-and-what-works-in-my-a/16699464#16699464) for an identical question.

Comment: Thx, it works now. The document use the same term  "your-app-id" for different things. really confuse me.